# SOO Go Subpackage Naming

Tags: go, package

I am porting a large web application to Go. In order to manage complexity and increase testability, we are employing a service-oriented architecture. I am trying to figure out the clearest way to name and structure packages such that no service has any knowledge of another's implementation and that I can tell them apart at the application level. Allow me to give an example:

FooService

```
package api

type FooService interface {
    foo()
}
```

FooService Implementation

```
package implementation

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/user/foo/api"
)

type FooImplementation struct {
}

func (self FooImplementation) foo() {
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

In my application, I will need to bind this implementation to the interface, as well as numerous others. But they can't all be named api/implementation. Do I have too name the packages fooapi and fooimplementation? Or is there a better way to structure my application?
Thanks!

Comment: What would be wrong if the service **and** implementation would live in the same package `github.com/user/foo`? You could still provide different impls in other packages or in tests? Not all best practices from e.g. Java carry over to Go.

Comment: Also have a look at how golang.org/x/oauth2 is organized.

Comment: Just keep your API and implementation in the same package, only exporting the identifiers that are part of the public API.

Comment: Aedolon - that's kinda what i'm doing now. I'm making both foo service and the implementation a part of the foo package, and then for services I will import "github.com/user/foo/api", but for packages where I need both, e.g. main, I will rename them as I import them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential workaround but I'm not going to mark this closed because it's not ideal. I discovered that you can name your imports to disambiguate packages with the same name. E.g.

```
import (
fapi "github.com/user/foo/api"
fimplementation "github.com/user/foo/implementation"
)
```